# How do I convert a raw input string value to the value of a variable of the same name as the raw input in Python 2?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variables, casting

Here's what I mean:

```
foo = 25

bar = (raw_input("foobar: "))

print bar
```

And if "foo" is used as input, I want it to print 25 instead of "foo". Is this possible? How can I do this?

(I'm currently working in Python 2.)

Comment: you could use a dictionary.....`x={'foo':25} print(x[bar])`

Answer (score 0):

Use the eval() command:

```
foo = 25
bar = eval(raw_input("enter 'foo': "))
print (bar)
```